# Error using a constexpr as a template parameter within the same class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++11, constexpr

If I try to compile the following C++0x code, I get an error:

```
template<int n> struct foo { };

struct bar {
    static constexpr int number() { return 256; }

    void function(foo<number()> &);
};
```

With gcc 4.6.1, the error message is:

```
test.cc:6:27: error: ‘static constexpr int bar::number()’ used before its definition
test.cc:6:28: note: in template argument for type ‘int’
```

With clang 2.8, the error message is:

```
test.cc:6:20: error: non-type template argument of type 'int' is not an integral
      constant expression
        void function(foo<number()> &);
                          ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

If I move the `constexpr` function to a base class, it works on gcc, and gives the same error message on clang:

```
template<int n> struct foo { };

struct base {
    static constexpr int number() { return 256; }
};

struct bar : base {
    void function(foo<number()> &);
};
```

Is the code wrong, or is it a limitation or bug on gcc 4.6's implementation of C++0x? If the code is wrong, why is it wrong, and which clauses of the C++11 standard say it is incorrect?

Comment: Hmm.. I think we just discussed this earlier: inline function definitions are treated as though they were defined *just after* the class definition; so inside the class definition they're not yet available. Note that you can always say `static const int number = 256;` or `static constexpr int number = 256;` instead.

Comment: @KerrekSB oh, I never knew that. You should write that as an answer.

Comment: @KerrekSB: AFAIK, if I use `static const int number = 256;`, I also need a `const int bar::number;`, which would wastefully add 4 useless bytes to `.data`. Using an inline function prevents that. I have no idea if that is also the case for `static constexpr int number = 256;`, however.

Comment: @CesarB: No, not necessarily. As long as you never attempt to take the address, you don't actually need to provide an implementation of a static constant.

Comment: @KerrekSB: looking at this C++0x draft I have, I see at [class.static.data]: "The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-used [...]", and at [basic.def.odr]: "[...] A variable whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is odr-used unless it is an object that satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is immediately applied. [...]". Looks like you are right, depending on what [expr.const] and [conv.lval] say. Even better, this way does it not need any `#ifndef` for MSVC!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, inline definitions of member functions for a class are only parsed after every declaration in the class is parsed.  Therefore, in your first example, the compiler can't see the definition of `number()` at the point where `function()` is declared.

(No released version of clang has support for evaluating constexpr functions, so none of your testcases will work there.)

Answer (score 1):

This will compile successfully:

```
struct Sub{constexpr Sub(int i){}};
struct Test{
    static constexpr Sub s=0;
};
```