# Getting the number of elements in std::array at compile time

Tags: c++

Is the following a valid C++ code, and why not?

```
std::array<std::string, 42> a1;
std::array<int, a1.size()> a2;
```

It doesn't compile in GCC 4.8 (in C++11 mode). There is a simple but inelegant workaround:

```
std::array<std::string, 42> a1;
std::array<int, sizeof(a1)/sizeof(a1[0])> a2;
```

So clearly the compiler can figure out the number of elements in std::array. Why std::array::size() is not a `constexpr static` function?

EDIT:
I have found another workaround:

```
std::array<std::string, 42> a1;
std::array<int, std::tuple_size<decltype(a1)>::value> a2;
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`array<T>::size()` is `constexpr`, but you can't use it in this way because `a1` isn't a `constexpr` value.  Additionally, it can't be `constexpr` because `string` isn't a literal type.

However, you can work around this if you want, by deducing the `size_t` template parameter.  Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename>
struct array_size;
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct array_size<array<T,N> > {
    static size_t const size = N;
};

array<string, 42> a1;
array<string, array_size<decltype(a1)>::size> a2;

int main() {
    cout << a2.size() << endl;
}
```

Comment: And that's why `size()` should be a `static` function, as suggested in the question.

Comment: @BenVoigt If size was a static constexpr function, there would be no problem?

Comment: @robson: Right, because then it would be `constexpr` depending only on whether all arguments are `constexpr` (trivially met since there are zero arguments) and not depending on whether the object instance `*this` is `constexpr`.

Comment: In fact, there is such a `array_size` deducing template already in the standard library: [`std::tuple_size<some_array_type>::value`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_size) (C++11). In C++17, you'll additionally find the usual convenience helper `std::tuple_size_v<some_array_type>`.

Answer (score 11):

`std::array::size` is actually required to be `constexpr` per § 23.3.2.1 of the C++11 standard:

```
23.3.2.4 array::size [array.size]  
template <class T, size_t N> constexpr size_type array<T,N>::size() noexcept;  
Returns: N
```

<s>I'm guessing this just slipped past whoever implemented it in GCC.</s>

---

After testing, this works:

```
std::array<int, 42> a1;
std::array<int, a1.size()> a2;
```

This may actually have something to do with `std::string` not being a valid `constexpr` type to make compile-time instances of, whereas `int` is.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the same template-inference method as has always been used for C++98 array bound detection.

```
template<size_t N, typename T>
constant_integer<N> array_size( const std::array<T, N>& );
```

- Demo: http://ideone.com/R4k1vG

Make a nice macro wrapper and enjoy!

Many variations are also possible, such as:

- http://ideone.com/Hn46ei

Answer (score 0):

It is not static but it is a `constexpr` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/size/
EDIT: this may not be a bug, take a look at this [Error using a constexpr as a template parameter within the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108314/error-using-a-constexpr-as-a-template-parameter-within-the-same-class)

Answer (score 0):

[`std::tuple_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple_size) has a specialization for `std::array` for this purpose:

```cpp
std::array<int, 42> a1;
std::array<int, std::tuple_size<decltype(a1)>::value> a2;
```

Since C++17 can use a shorthand [`std::tuple_size_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/tuple_size):

```cpp
std::array<int, 42> a1;
std::array<int, std::tuple_size_v<decltype(a1)>> a2;
```